# Why does Visual Studio 2017 shows me error, when I use std::wstring?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, std

I just want to use `std::wstring` in my code just for learning purposes, but when i run this code (below) using Visual Studio 2017, it showns me error (below the code).

code:

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include "pch.h"

int main() {
    double f = 23.32;
    std::wstring f_str = std::to_wstring(f);
    std::wcout << f_str;
}
```

error:

```
Error   C2039   'wstring': is not a member of 'std'
```

Comment: Do you have `#include <string>` somewhere above the `main` function?

Comment: you need to include <wstring>

Comment: I have included `#include<string>` above `main`, but when I include `<wstring>`, it showed me another error: `cannot open source file "wstring"`

Comment: According to cppreference [std::basic_string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), `#include <string>` should be fine. What project type have you chosen in VS2017 to set-up your solution?

Comment: @Scheff `Visual C++ Windows Console Application`

Comment: What are your settings in Project Properties - General - Project Defaults - Character Set?

Comment: @wimh Character Set is `**Use Unicode Character Set**`

Comment: I tried all solutions mentioned here in the post, nothing worked for me (my project is already setup to use "Unicode Character Set". The only thing I changed in 'pch.h' (stdafx.h in VC++ MFC app) is converting #include <string.h> to **#include <string>**.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are using a pre-compiled header `"pch.h"`.

The header `"pch.h"` should be included before all other header files.

If the precompiled header file is `"pch.h"` and the compile option is `/Yu`, Visual Studio will not compile anything before the `#include "pch.h"` in the source file; it assumes all code in the source up to and including that line is already compiled.

So you just have to change the order of inclusion of the header files such that `"pch.h"` is the first header to be included.

Comment: Great explanation

Comment: @GugaNemsitsveridze: Thanks. :)